# Mobile website with CSS, but doesn't respond to screen size?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I've just completed a [mobile site](http://courtesycabsd.com/m) for a client, and I've mainly focused on the website's lightness and responsiveness. I haven't worked on redirecting the website because it's still a work in progress BUT all the vital components have been done.
Now if you view the website in your computer and resize your browser, you'll see how it changes according to the viewport's width. But I tried viewing it in my smartphone (Samsung Galaxy S2) and I end up seeing the whole website squished into the available viewport.
Why is this happening and what do I do to make it work?
Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: Did you put a viewpoint meta tag in the code?

Comment: No.. haven't added any. Is that the only thing I'm missing?

Comment: Viewport will force the scale. You can also set a range and turn the users ability to zoom on and off.

Comment: My though is that your slider is not responsive. The rest of your content seems to scale just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I believe this is the code I should use? <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

Comment: Ah, I found what I was supposed to do. Adding <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> to the head section did what it was supposed to. Thank you all for your feedbacks. Much appreciated!

Comment: what you generally want is <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">  Good luck!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Mobile browsers won't know what to do unless you specifically instruct them.**

[The viewport metatag is essential](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/) when designing responsive layouts. To fix this problem, simply add the following tag to your website's `<head>`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

If you feel that you need to zoom out a tiny bit more (I personally prefer this), you can also make some small tweaks to get a cool look:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.7">
```

Have fun,

Adam.

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSS. You haven't closed your curly brace. or you have typo error.

```
/* =Responsive: Small screen to tablet & IPAD
-------------------------------------------------------------- */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) {
.navbar .nav li a {
 padding-right: 5px;
 pading-left: 5px;
}
```

example css.